# SpriteKit a way to know when 2 physics bodies are no longer in contact

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have 2 physics bodies a player and a shelf.

I am using `- (void)didbeginContact...`
To know when a player begins to touch the shelf.

However I Also need to know when player no longer touches the shelf.

I am looking at the docs but I can't find anything

I found `- (void)didEndContact ..`
But it is not what I need since it triggers when I start touching the shelf :(

Is there anyway to know it directly from physic bodies 
Or do I have to find another way to know it ?

How can I do so using sprite kit ?

The did end contact

```
- (void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact   
{
    //End contact with the shelf!
    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == SHELF_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == JULIE_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY )|| (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == SHELF_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == JULIE_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY))
    {

           NSLog(@"No more contact"); //But there is :(

    }
}
```

Player node PhysicsBody properties initialisation

```
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
    self.physicsBody.mass = 10;

    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = JULIE_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = SHELF_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = SHELF_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY;
```

Shelf node PhysicsBody properties

```
         self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.size];
        self.physicsBody.mass = 100;
        self.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
        self.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = SHELF_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY;
```

x_BIT_MASK_CATEGORY are defines

Comment: Can you please post your full code? Do you have restitution enabled? If the sprite bounces at all, didEndContact will be fired for each bounce.

Comment: Yes I have it enabled (I guess).
The point is when the player jumps from the shelf the `- (void)didEndContact..` does't fire :( I posting my code

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You say it does fire when you start touching the shelf in your questions, but then you just says it does not fire. Can you please post more code? How are you creating your physics bodies?

Comment: Jumps FROM means stops to touch -- I am sorry I am not native English speaker.

Comment: Sorry misread it. Please post your physics body creation.

Comment: I posted the initialisation code: -- My player is jumping from shelf to shelf , but there is a situation when player can just keep running and to fall from the shelf, I thought to get this case by being notified that the contact with the shelf has ended.

Comment: Are you missing the `contactTestBitMask` and `categoryBitMask for the Shelf?

Comment: hmm perhaps but should it really help me ?

Comment: Try adding those in. Also, are you removing your character while contact is still happening?

Comment: You could try a while loop that checks if there is contact and when the loop is no longer true you could have it run the next block of code

Comment: @Oliver While loop will hang the CPU isn't it ? and then the fps will drop

Comment: @Siriss It is late at night now , I will sure try tomorrow and let you know Thanks

Comment: Okay thanks for help , I solved the problem, I made the bodies not to bounce thanks for @Siriss, and I added state machine to the player , so I can filter unwanted 'didEndContacts' . Thanks for help guys !